# VSCode, keep running into a module error despite installing said module in my python shell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, nltk

So I've been trying to clean up my word dictionary data by removing stop words and words where the count is less than 1000.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 

def cleanSmallData():
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
delete = [key for key in totalWordsDict if totalWordsDict[key] < 1000]   

for key in delete:
    del totalWordsDict[key]
##Stopword Filter
delete1 = [key for key in totalWordsDict if not key in stop_words]
for key in delete1:
    del totalWordsDict[key]
```

totalWordsDict is a dictionary containing a word key and a count value.
When I run this code after commenting out the import and the code after the Stopword filter, it works fine.

This is the error I keep running into:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

I've pip installed nltk for Python 3.8.2 (same installation that I'm running this code on), as well as downloaded all of its packages through the shell by using nltk.download('all'), but I'm still running into this error.

Comment: Figured it out. I pip installed into the directory where I had the code and it worked.

Comment: Hi @Kered! I suggest you to answer to your own question, and explain how did you managed to solve your problem. This will help next user who will face the same issue as you.